# Trying to get two while loops to run concurrently using threading or multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop

According to examples online, these two methods I've tried should be the solution to my problem (see code). These two while loops are running one after the other even through they are in separate threads.

I've tried threading and multiprocessing.

```
    global numberit
    numberit= 0
    global numberg
    numberg= 0
    def countingit(numberit):
        while numberit < 10:
            numberit += 1
            print("counter ", numberit)
            # time.sleep(1)

    def garbage(numberg):
        while numberg < 10:
            numberg += 1
            print("garbage ", numberg)
            # time.sleep(1)


    # threading.Thread(target=countingit(numberit)).start()
    # threading.Thread(target=garbage(numberg)).start()

    if  __name__ == '__main__':
        Process(target=countingit(numberit)).start()
        Process(target=garbage(numberg)).start()
    #     threading.Thread(target=countingit(numberit)).start()
    #     threading.Thread(target=garbage(numberg)).start()
```

I'm trying to get it to print:

counter 1
garbage 1
counter 2
garbage 2

... and so on.

The plan is to run while loop threads concurrently with a tkinter gui with push buttons. but i cant get them to run at the same time. One process always has to complete before the other starts.

Thank you.

I've already tried what is shown in the example code I have provided.

Instead of having each while loop run in intervals, I get them running one after the other which is not the desired outcome. I'm trying this as a test to then add a tkinter gui in another thread.

This is the result:

counter  1
...
counter  10
garbage  1
...
garbage  10

But would like:
counter 1
garbage 1
...
counter 10
garbage 10

Comment: _"I've already tried what is shown in the example code I have provided."_ There must be a formatting problem with your post -- I see the _output_ of your code but I don't see the code itself. Please [edit] your post and make sure your example code is visible.

Comment: Just finished editing if you care to take a loop @kevin

Comment: Thanks, I can see it now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a problem in these two lines:

```
 threading.Thread(target=countingit(numberit)).start()
 threading.Thread(target=garbage(numberg)).start()
```

This is a common antipattern -- instead of making a thread that calls `countingit` with the argument `numberit`, this code calls `countingit` right away in the main thread, and then passes the return value to the Thread initializer.

To pass arguments to a function being called by a thread, use the `args` parameter. Make sure to pass it as a tuple, even if there's only one argument.

```
threading.Thread(target = countingit, args=(numberit,)).start()
threading.Thread(target = garbage, args=(numberit,)).start()
```

When I run this on my machine, I get output that is interleaved as desired:

```
counter  1
counter  2
garbage  1
counter  3
garbage  2
counter  4
counter  5
garbage  3
counter  6
counter  7
garbage  4
counter  8
garbage  5
counter  9
garbage  6
counter  10
garbage  7
garbage  8
garbage  9
garbage  10
```

(all of this advice applies to your Process-based attempt, as well)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin!